# How To Permanently Lock the "Fn" Key Down So It Is Active On My Laptop Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys, media-keys

I would like to know how to permanently lock the "Fn" key down so it is active on my keyboard. I'm running and HP G72. I could not figure out the Key Code using any macro software.

I want the Fn key to be inverted... so that it is ON all the time, and pressing and holding it turns off temporarily.

The reason is that the stupid multimedia controls now have priority on the F1 - F12 keys. Pressing them activates some multimedia function. I want to use them as default F-keys, namely F5 for refresh, but I have to manually press and hold Fn + F5 which is a pain.

I want it to be enabled in all of windows so its the flip of how it behaves normally.
Any help is appreciated, I spend like 3 hours trying to figure it out already... thanks!

Comment: Ok this has a duplicate, link please admins. If you're gonna mark something as a dupe, please be helpful and give the link.

Answer (score 8):

This is done in the bios on that specific model as explained here: [Disable The Fn + Function Key Combination on Certain Models](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02035108&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN)

> On most HP and Compaq notebook computers, it is necessary to press and
>   hold the function key (fn) while pressing one of the f1 through f12
>   keys to activate the default functions; such as, increasing or
>   decreasing the brightness of the display, the sound volume, sleep,
>   keyboard lock, etc. On the HP Envy notebooks and other notebooks with
>   advanced BIOS options, the function keys can be configured so that it
>   is not necessary to press and hold the fn key.

Answer (score 2):

At Dell models it is also in BIOS settings. At Advanced tab you can switch between Multimedia keys and Function keys.