# Enable FN-Keys per default / lock them

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a [mechanical Keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DBJTZU2) and am using Windows 10. The Keyboard provides some FN-key like volume up etc.

To use them I have to press the FN-key Right before. However, as I normally don't use the F1-F12 keys for its normal functionality like refresh etc., is there the possibility to change some settings in Windows so that when I normally press 'F7' for example this always executes the special command "Next Track" instead of the the F7 functionality?

So I am Looking for something like Caps-Lock for the FN-Keys. Or does this all depend on the Keyboard-model I am using and cannot be configured in Windows directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Permanently Lock the "Fn" Key Down So It Is Active On My Laptop Keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/235796/how-to-permanently-lock-the-fn-key-down-so-it-is-active-on-my-laptop-keyboard)

Comment: I foreget the exact setting name, but sometimes it can be changed in your bios or uefi settings

Comment: Oh i forgot to Mention that I am not using the Laptop Keyboard but an external one. Maybe I wrote thos a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

No. In this case, FN-key present on the keyboard does its job only within the keyboard, not transmitting or receiving its state to the computer. (It is invisible to the computer.) So no control nor settings from the PC.

The possible solution (if you are sitting at a desk) is to have another [keyboard with exposed media keys](https://www.google.com/search?q=keyboard%20with%20media%20keys&tbm=isch) nearby.